# Firebase update top level value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update a counter record in my firebase DB, I can update just fine when the data is nested, however, I am having trouble updating the value of "total" if it is at the top level.

JSON:

```
{
  "accounts" : {
    "-KRPSyO4B48IpBnHBTYg" : {
      "dateCreated" : "",
      "email" : "",
      "provider" : "",
      "userId" : ""
    }
  },
  "products" : {
    "-KUKRafaNurpFhGF4jQa" : {
      "dateCreated" : "",
      "description" : "",
      "imageUrl" : "",
      "lastUpdated" : "",
      "name" : "",
      "postCount" : -1,
      "tags" : [ "Tag" ],
      "url" : "",
      "viewCount" : 10,

    }
  },
  "total" : 1
}
```

This simply replaces the value of "total" with 100, however I want to add 1 to that every time something happens.  I realize that here I am not retrieving the value of "total" first, and that is part of my problem, I'm having trouble getting that value as well..

```
firebase.database().ref().update({
 total: + 100
                });
```

My other counters look like this and update other nested values quite well:

```
firebase.database().ref('products/' + product.id).update({
 postCount: product.postCount + 1,
 viewCount: product.viewCount + 1

                });
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you're incrementing values of a property like this you should be using a Transaction. Because when two users have different local values for that property one update will overwrite the other. Also, it will help you get the current value of that property.

I think this code should do what you want.

```
firebase.database().ref('total').transaction(function(value) {
  if (value) {
    value++;
  }
  return value;
});
```

You can read up on Transactions here: 
[Firebase Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)

Comment: Like a charm!  Thanks!